# Facebook sharing option is not available in ios 8 using an UIActivitycontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I have to share Text appending with the `url` using the `UIActivityController`. It shows Email, twitter and other sharing. But Facebook sharing is not shown. I have already signed in with the Facebook too.

Here is my code.

```
NSString *str_link = @"www.examplelink.com";
NSArray *movieitems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Check out this really cool!\n", str_link, nil]; 

UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:movieitems applicationActivities:nil];

[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Have you signed to Facebook from the iOS Settings app or from native Facebook app?

Comment: yes  i have signed in from  iOS Settings app. and also check with signed in from native Facebook app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this adding an `url` instead of adding array of strings.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:str_link];
movieitems = @[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Check out this really cool!\n"], url];
```

Now I have faced if I post using facebook only a link is shared. The text I added (`@"Check out this really cool!"`) is ignored.

Comment: please try to change to the following: `movieitems = @[ @"Check out this really cool!", url ];`

Comment: Thank you. I have fixed it.